# How do I get the type name passed in a generic method call?

Tags: java, generics

I need to implement a method functionally similar to the following:

```
static <T extends Object> T validateObj (T obj) throws ValidationException {
  // ValidationException is a custom Exception class
  if (obj == null) {
    throw new ValidationException(T.class.getSimpleName() + errorMsgTemplate);
  } else {
    return obj;
  }
}
```

An example of how the function is used by the system:

```
try {
  RandomAccessFile file = getFile(pathName, "r");  // Custom method. May return null
  file = Validator.validateObj(file);
} catch (Exception e) {
  // Handle exception
}
// Use file
```

In attempting to log errors, how can I obtain the class name of T for each particular method call regardless of whether the actual object passed is `null` or not? The type of the object variable to be passed into the validation method is always known by the method caller.

**Update**: While I chose Bambino's answer, here's a shoutout to StuPointerException's answer as well. Due to the restrictions of dealing with existing code, his answer is more suitable for my specific problem. However, I do believe Bambino's answer is the more correct implementation solution in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-) for your required functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible I'm afraid; `getClass` returns the class of the object.  When you have `null`, you don't have an object so you can't get the type of it.

One way yo get around this is to force the caller to include a reference to the class that they are (or might be) passing:

`static <T extends Object> T validateObj (T obj, Class<?> clazz) throws ValidationException {`

Comment: Hmm, so you mean to pass the class name from the outside? Any idea if doing it your way or passing a String value of `simpleName()` is better in terms of the load on overheads, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Definitely pass the `class`, this is a standard pattern to get around scenarios like this.  There are minimal overheads either way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a generic method of the form

```
static <T> T validateObj(T obj) {
    // code
}
```

then the type of `T` is determined by the class of the object you pass in. That is, `T` will always be exactly the type of what you pass in. This means you can call `obj.getClass()` to get the class, as long as it's not null.

If you pass in `null`, it will treat `T` as though it were `Object`.